# Which kind of function it is? What is the return type of such function? why they use star(*) before func name

Tags: c++, function, pointers, linked-list

```
  int *fun() 
{ 
    //CODE
}
```

**Why they use * before function name? can anyone please refer me something about this or please explain.**

Comment: Please use a tag for the language you are using.  If it's C or C++, this declares the function as returning a pointer.  This will be explained in literally every book or course on C or C++.

Comment: it is in c++ , got it , would you please reffer me a good book for c++.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a particular book in mind, and book recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SouravDebnath There is stack overflow list of recommended C++ books here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list